# How can I ensure that only the parent element is captured for a click event?

Tags: reactjs, events, onclick, event-handling

I have this simple Ticket React component. I want to only capture the surrounding `<tr>` parent element, but sometimes if I click on one of the table cells it will give me a `<td>` element.

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Ticket.module.css";

const Ticket = (props) => {

  let toggleModal = props.onToggleModal;

  const eventToggle = (event) => {
    // console.log(event.target.innerText);
    toggleModal(event);
  }

  return (
    <tr className={styles.ticket} onClick={eventToggle}>
      <td className={styles["ticket-col"]}>
        <div>
        {props.ticket.task}
        </div>
        </td>
      <td className={styles["ticket-col"]}>
        <div>
        {props.ticket.assignee}
        </div>
        </td>
      <td className={styles["ticket-col"]}>
        <div>
        {props.ticket.time}
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

export default Ticket;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `event.target` (the innermost item that was clicked on) is a `<tr>`, and not anything else. (Otherwise, if it's a `<td>` or a `<div>` or something else, the click was on some other inner element.)

```
const Ticket = (props) => {
  const eventToggle = (event) => {
    if (event.target.matches('tr')) {
      props.onToggleModal(event);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I don't think that will work because I need to retrieve and encapsulate all the data when I click on a row. If a user is able to click on a single table data cell then I will only get the data from that one cell. I need the data from all 3 cells.

Comment: The data is available in the props - just reference the props. (perhaps you need to pass the props when calling `onToggleModal`?)

Comment: Interesting. I thought you could only pass props in one direction. Thanks.

Comment: There are other ways to do it. You could, if you wanted, somehow bind the data with the event handler in the parent. `<Ticket onToggleModal={() => foo(task, assignee, time)} ...` But passing the values back up is fine as well.